Is everything okay with this Presale contract?
Could you help me check if this presale contract does what it's supposed to do and if it's safe? I tried to find bugs or flaws but couldn't find anything.
The theory is very simple: the user can use the receiveETH function to buy the tokens or they can simply send ether directly to the contract which will have the same effect. The owner will be able to withdraw the ethers and then change the pause variable so that the claim function can be used by users. What do you think, is everything in order?
Detail: tctAdress is the address of the token contract which will be already deployed at this point.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

import "./TestContract.sol";


contract PreSale {
    TestContract tct;

    address public owner;
    mapping(address account => uint256) private _balances;
    address public tctAdress = 0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138;

    uint256 public tokenSupply = 0;    
    uint256 totalPurchases = 0;
    uint256 public presalePrice = 2000000000000 wei;    // price of 1 tct in wei (1 tct = 0.000002 ETH)
    
    bool private paused = true;    // pauses all claims
    bool internal locked;    // lock claim state when executing

    event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
        tct = TestContract(tctAdress);
    }

    modifier noReentrancy() {
        require(!locked, "No reentrancy allowed");
        locked = true;
        _;
        locked = false;
    }

    function getETHBalance() public view returns(uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view virtual returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function pausedStatus() public view virtual returns (bool) {
        return paused;
    }

    function updatePreSaleTokenBalance() public {
        tct = TestContract(tctAdress);

        tokenSupply = tct.balanceOf(address(this));
    }

    // User is giving ETH to receive tokens later
    function receiveETH() external payable { 
        address user = msg.sender;
        uint256 ethAmount = msg.value;

        _receiveETH(user, ethAmount);
    } 

    // User claim tokens with this function call
    function claim() external noReentrancy {
        tct = TestContract(tctAdress);

        address user = msg.sender;
        uint256 value = _balances[user];
        bool status;

        // Verify if it is possible to claim tokens
        require(!paused, "Presale not finished, not possible to claim tokens at this moment");

        // Transfer tokens to the user
        require(_balances[user] > 0, "No tokens to be claimed");
        status = tct.transfer(user, value);

        // Update the number of tokens in the contract
        _balances[user] = 0;
        updatePreSaleTokenBalance();
        emit Transfer(address(this), user, value);
    }

    // Unpaused claim function
    function unpausedClaim() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        paused = false;
    }

    // Paused claim function
    function pausedClaim() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        paused = true;
    }

    // Send ethers to the project's wallet
    function withdraw(uint256 ethAmount) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can call this function");
        payable(owner).transfer(ethAmount);
    }

    function _receiveETH(address user, uint256 ethAmount) private {
        tct = TestContract(tctAdress);

        // Verify min and max limits.
        require(ethAmount > 5000000000000000 wei, "ETH amount must be > 0.005 ETH");
        require(ethAmount < 1000000000000000000 wei, "ETH amount must be < 1 ETH");

        // Calculates the amount of tokens the user will receive.
        uint256 tokenAmount = ethAmount / presalePrice;

        // Verify if the amount of ETH of the user is enough to continue the transaction   
        require(user.balance >= ethAmount, "Insufficient ETH balance to complete the transaction");

        // Verify if the amount of tokens left in this contract is enough to continue the transaction   
        uint256 leftTokens = tokenSupply - totalPurchases;
        require(leftTokens > tokenAmount, "Insufficient token balance to complete the transaction"); 

        // Updates.
        _balances[user] += tokenAmount; 
        totalPurchases += tokenAmount;
        emit Transfer(user, address(this), ethAmount);
    }

    receive() external payable {
        address user = msg.sender;
        uint256 ethAmount = msg.value;

        _receiveETH(user, ethAmount);
    }

}

